# How to convert images into a dataset for semantic segmentation

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to make a new semantic segmentation model that will take grainy microscopy images as input and segment them.

[image: Input Image]

[image: Output Image]

I have all the input and ground truth images in .png format, and I'm having a hard time curating them into a dataset that others can use. I've looked into some articles, but they explain how to make label images that I already have. So, is there a way/software which I can use to curate the dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the open-source tool, [FiftyOne](https://fiftyone.ai), to curate the dataset in a way that allows you to [share it](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/faq/index.html#can-i-share-a-dataset-with-someone-else) and also easily [visualize](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/app.html), [explore](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_views.html), and [analyze](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/brain.html) it along with any future model predictions.

[FiftyOne](https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone) has a Python API that will load your [instance](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_datasets.html#instance-segmentations) or [semantic segmentation labels](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_datasets.html#semantic-segmentation) into a [FiftyOne Dataset](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/using_datasets.html) which you can then query and visualize in the App (both the raw images and the annotations).

[image]

If you store your images and segmentations on disk in this file structure:

```
segmentation_dataset
   |
   |
   +--- data
   |      |
   |      +--- 000.png
   |      +--- 001.png
   |      +--- 000.png
   |      ...
   |
   +--- labels
          |
          +--- 000.png
          +--- 001.png
          +--- 000.png
          ...
```

Then you can load it into Python and visualize it with these lines of code:

```py
import fiftyone as fo

dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir(
    "segmentation_dataset",
    dataset_type=fo.types.ImageSegmentationDirectory,
    name="segmentation_dataset",
    force_grayscale=True,
)

# Visualize the dataset in your browser
session = fo.launch_app(dataset)
```

Note: Use the [force_grayscale](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.utils.data.importers.html#fiftyone.utils.data.importers.ImageSegmentationDirectoryImporter) argument to load RGB masks like the one you provided.

#### Sharing the dataset

You can add and modify samples and labels on your dataset with the FiftyOne API and then [export it to disk](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/export_datasets.html) in a variety of formats (VOC, COCO, YOLO, CVAT, etc). From there you can zip it and let others easily load it back into FiftyOne.

For example, we can use the [`FiftyOneDataset` format](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/export_datasets.html#fiftyonedataset) as it works for any label type:

```py
dataset.export(
    export_dir="/path/to/export_dir",
    dataset_type=fo.types.FiftyOneDataset
)
```

Zip the dataset and send it to someone else, they can now run:

```py
import fiftyone as fo

dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir(
    dataset_dir="/path/to/unzipped_dataset",
    dataset_type=fo.types.FiftyOneDataset,
)
```

#### Splits

If you store splits of data in the folder structure shown below:

```
segmentation_dataset
   |
   |
   +--- Train
   |      |
   |      +--- data
   |      |      |
   |      |      +--- 000.png
   |      |      +--- 001.png
   |      |      +--- 000.png
   |      |      ...
   |      |
   |      +--- labels
   |             |
   |             +--- 000.png
   |             +--- 001.png
   |             +--- 000.png
   |             ...   
   +--- Test
   |      |
   |      ...
   ...
```

You can then load all of the samples into a dataset and add a [tag](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/app.html#tags-and-tagging) to each one denoting which split it belongs to.

```py
import fiftyone as fo

dataset_type = fo.types.ImageSegmentationDirectory

dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir(
    dataset_dir="segmentation_dataset/Train",
    dataset_type=dataset_type,
    tags="train",
    name="segmentation_dataset",
)

dataset.add_dir(
    dataset_dir="segmentation_dataset/Test",
    dataset_type=dataset_type,
    tags="test",
)
```

#### Training a model

From there, you can use this dataset directly to train a model (for example with [PyTorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-wasting-time-with-pytorch-datasets-17cac2c22fa8) or [PyTorch Lightning Flash](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/lightning_flash.html#model-training))

Answer (score 1):

You can organize the images along similar to the organization in the [VOC challenge](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/).

That is, you should have the following directory tree:

```
my_dataset
   |
   +---  InputImages
   |           |
   |           +---   000.png
   |           +---   001.png
   |           +---   002.png
   |           ...
   |
   +---  SegmentationMasks
   |           |
   |           +---   000.png
   |           +---   001.png
   |           +---   002.png
   |           ...
   |  
   +---  ImageSets 
               |
               +---   train.txt
               +---   val.txt
               +---   test.txt
```

That is, you store all input images under `InputImages` folder and all the segmentation masks you have under `SegmentationMasks` folder. Make sure the mask `SegmentationMasks/000.png` corresponds to `InputImages/000.png` (and so on for all images and masks).

Additionally, you can have a fixed split of your dataset into "train", "validation" and "test" sets. This split is stored in the test files under `ImageSets`:
The file `train.txt` lists the image ids that are part of the train set, `val.txt` lists the ids of the validation set and so on.
Make sure all ids are included in the split, and no image appears in two splits.
(That is, the union of "train.txt" + "val.txt" + "test.txt" = all ids, and the intersection is empty).

Comment: After organising like this how can we pass it to a model like shown here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation